# is there a way to get the original order of map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, go-map

I have a use case where the input payload consumed by my REST endpoint should flush it in the same order.

There is no specific pattern to the input, so I'm saving it as `map[string]interface{}` and that is causing the issue. Because the input is not mapped to a specific struct the original order is not getting honoured and is getting randomised.

I know that's how `map[string]interface{}` is supposed to work but is there a way to retain or get the original order ?

The only solution I can think off is, not to use `map[string]interface{}` but to save the payload to a file, process it from there and then flush it out at the end. -->  If this is the solution that I should perceive, then, what additional checks should I consider since this involves files. The endpoint is very lightweight, payload is considerably small with less parallel calls.

edit1:

example input payload,

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "test": "testing",
  "example": 1,
  "nested": {
      "foo": "foo-nested",
      "key": 1,
  },
}
```

Comment: A map does not have an order.  Possible workarounds are: store the keys in a slice, store  key-value pairs in a slice, write the key-values to the output as they are read and others.  There's insufficient information information in the question to provide more actionable advice.   For example, you don't tell us the data format of the input our output.

Comment: Asking about "retaining the original order" is like asking about "retaining the phlogiston of a body": There _is_ no such think, you thus cannot retain it. If you are talking about JSON-->map: Write your own Unmarshaler that remembers the order of the JSON byte stream.

Comment: @CeriseLimón added an example payload the input payload takes json input with dynamic key vaules

Comment: Maybe use [linkedhashmap](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/emirpasic/gods/maps/linkedhashmap)? It even has built-in JSON support.

Comment: The example is helpful, but we still don't know what the application is doing with the data. Is it sufficient to copy the bytes as is from input to output?  If not, edit the question to provide more information.